# Does hash values contain quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, sql-injection, phpass

Does hash values contain quotes?

If it is dependent to the algorithm, I want to know about `blowfish` using `phpass`.

I'm asking  in regard to SQL injection because I don't want `prepare` the query for `authentication` and use `place holders`, just wrapping the `username` and `password hash` in quotes. ( I also have doubt that is `username` safe when just be validated to only consist of `word chars [a-wA-W1-9_]` (no quotes or other special chars)? )

Comment: Validating the username to only contain chars you feel able to deal with is a good idea. But also respect your database client library and make use of the features it offers like prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, hash values can contain quotes. As well as usernames.

You should also not base your database-interaction on the fragile assumption that they never should have (because you hope so much to not prepare which sounds ridiculous).

Instead make the database query as safe as possible regardless what you assume the data will be. Sometimes things go wrong on some end and you don't want that error stored in your persistence layer nor do you want to offer a potential door for SQL injection.